# Convert ES6 Iterable to Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, iterable, babeljs

Say you have an array-like Javascript ES6 Iterable that you know in advance will be finite in length, what's the best way to convert that to a Javascript Array?

The reason for doing so is that many js libraries such as underscore and lodash only support Arrays, so if you wish to use any of their functions on an Iterable, it must first be converted to an Array.

In python you can just use the list() function. Is there an equivalent in ES6?

Comment: `Array.from(iterable)`, see [*ECMA-262 ed 6 draft*](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-array.from).

Answer (score 271):

You can use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) or  [spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Example:

```js
const x = new Set([ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]);

const y = Array.from(x);
console.log(y); // = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]

const z = [ ...x ];
console.log(z); // = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

Comment: Almost the same applies to ES6 `let m = new Map()` data-structure: to get just values of the Map, use `Array.from` or spread operator on `m.values()`, same for `m.keys()`. Otherwise, you'll get an array of arrays: `[[key, value], [key, value]]`.

Answer (score 27):

### Summary:

- `Array.from()` function, it takes an iterable as in input and returns an array of the iterable.
- Spread syntax: `...` in combination with an array literal.

```js
const map = new Map([[ 1, 'one' ],[ 2, 'two' ]]);

const newArr1  = [ ...map  ];  // create an Array literal and use the spread syntax on it
const newArr2 = Array.from( map );  // 

console.log(newArr1, newArr2);
```

### Caveat when copying arrays:

Be cognizant of the fact that via these methods above only a shallow copy is created when we want to copy an array. An example will clarify the potential issue:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, ['a', 'b']];

let newArr = [ ...arr ];

console.log(newArr);

arr[2][0] = 'change';

console.log(newArr);
```

Here because of the nested array the reference is copied and no new array is created. Therefore if we mutate the inner array of the old array, this change will be reflected in the new array (because they refer to the same array, the reference was copied).

### Solution for caveat:

We can resolve the issue of having shallow copies by creating a deep clone of the array using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array))`. For example:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, ['a', 'b']]

let newArr = Array.from(arr);

let deepCloneArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));

arr[2][0] = 'change';

console.log(newArr, deepCloneArr)
```

Comment: This `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));` can now be changed to `structuredClone(arr)`

Answer (score 15):

You can use the [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) method, which is being added in ES6, but only supports arrays and iterable objects like Maps and Sets (also coming in ES6). For regular objects, you can use Underscore's [toArray](http://underscorejs.org/#toArray) method or lodash's toArray method, since both libraries actually have great support for objects, not just arrays. If you are already using underscore or lodash, then luckily they can handle the problem for you, alongside adding various functional concepts like map and reduce for your objects.

Answer (score 3):

The following approach is tested for Maps:

```
const MyMap = new Map([
  ['a', 1],
  ['b', 2],
  ['c', 3]
]);

const MyArray = [...MyMap].map(item => {
  return {[item[0]]: item[1]}
});

console.info( MyArray ); //[{"a", 1}, {"b", 2}, {"c": 3}]
```

Comment: Not what was asked - see the Array.from way

Answer (score -2):

You could also do the following, but both approaches are certainly not recommendable (merely a proof-of-concept for completeness):

```
let arr = [];
for (let elem of gen(...)){
    arr.push(elem);
}
```

Or "the hard way" using ES5 + generator function ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xyL8u7z7/1/) works in current Firefox):

```js
var squares = function* (n) {
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    yield i * i;
  }
};

var arr = [];
var gen = squares(10);
var g;
while (true) {
  g = gen.next();
  if (g.done) {
    break;
  }
  arr.push(g.value);
}
```