# Why does javascript's ES6/Harmony Set objects return empty objects for the keys/values/entries methods?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm trying out the new `Set` object in node 4.1.2 and I'm seeing that the `values`, `keys`, and `entries` methods all always return empty objects. For example:

```
var x = new Set
x.add(1)
x.add(2)
x.values() // returns {}
```

Is this expected behavior? I can't imagine it is.

Comment: Isn't `x.values()` an iterator?  What happens if you `.next().value` it?

Comment: Heyyy, `x.values().next().value` seems to work. That leads to the question: why does javascript have iterators? And since it has iterators, why don't they work in `for(x in y)` loops?

Comment: Because you use `for ( let z of x ) {console.log(z);}` now

Comment: Ah I see. Its not actually that "you use ..`of`.. now" - the use of `for..in` hasn't changed at all. Rather, `for..of` is a new construction that iterates over values rather than keys, and since iterators have no keys, `in` doesn't have anything to loop through. I still think they would have done well to stay away from the concept of iterators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES6 has added some new tricks including iteration protocols.  You may want to take a look at [Iteration Protocols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) on MDN to get a tighter grasp on how to utilize them.  `for(item in array)` is still around, but you can use the new `for ... of` on certain things.

Considering your code:

```
var x = new Set
x.add(1)
x.add(2)
x.values()
```

Let us say that, where `var y = x.values();`, `y` is an iterator;

In order to iterate over said iterator, you use a `for(let item of iterable){}` loop.  In this instance, you would be using:

```
for(let z of x){
    console.log(z);
}
```

Which would print out:

```
1
2
```

Comment: Looks like converting iterators to arrays isn't quite there in 2.5.0, but is there in v4: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27612713/convert-es6-iterable-to-array

Answer (score 0):

The values are there, it's just that `util.inspect()` was not showing them. This was fixed already in master with [88533881d](https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/88533881dd296236a44ad36aa7afb8336298540f), which was post-v4.1.2. So you will see the fix whenever v4.1.3 gets released.

Comment: `for(var n in x.values()) {console.log(n)}` logs nothing, so I don't think its just a `util.inspect()` problem.