# Immutable.js Map values to array

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I am using the immutable Map from http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map

I need to get an array of the values out to pass to a backend service and I think I am missing something basic, how do I do it ?

I have tried :

`mymap.valueSeq().toArray()`

But I still get an immutable data structure back ?

For example :

```
var d = '[{"address":"10.0.35.118","cpus":4}]';
var sr = JSON.parse(d);
var is = Immutable.fromJS(sr);

console.log(sr);

console.log(is.toArray());
console.log(is.valueSeq().toArray());
```

See this http://jsfiddle.net/3sjq148f/2/

The array that we get back from the immutable data structure seems to still be adorned with the immutable fields for each contained object. Is that to be expected ?

Comment: Can you give more details? Also I think you can give `toJS` a try.

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3sjq148f/1), work for me. You even don't need the `valueSeq`. Could you create a sample to reproduce it?

Comment: try this:
`var array = []

mymap.valueSeq().forEach(function(item){ array.push(item)})`

Comment: @fuyushimoya you right - back to the drawing board for me to check - thanks

Comment: @fuyushimoya I added an example above. The array of objects becomes a List of Maps afaics

Comment: @LenW, if you see its doc, Map's constructor seems don't accept `array` of `object`. It either accept Object like `{key: value}` or `array` of `array`: `[[key, value]]`, but not `[{key: value}]`.

Comment: @fuyushimoya thats why I am using `fromJS` ? Is that wrong ?

Comment: Oops, missed that, but then I believe it becomes a `Collection` of `Map`. Which means `is.valueSeq().toArray()` gives you an array of `Map`. You need to unwrap it further, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3sjq148f/3/).

Comment: @fuyushimoya is you put that as an answer then I can mark it correct. thanks all, it is the `toJS` that I was missing for the nested Maps

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's because the `sr` is an `Array` of `Object`, so if you use `.fromJS` to convert it, it becomes `List` of `Map`.

The `is.valueSeq().toArray();`(`valueSeq` is not necessary here.) converts it to `Array` of `Map`, so you need to loop through the array, and convert each `Map` item to `Array`.

```js
var d = '[{"address":"10.0.35.118","cpus":4}]';
var sr = JSON.parse(d);

// Array of Object => List of Map
var is = Immutable.fromJS(sr);

console.log(sr);
console.log(is.toArray());

// Now its Array of Map
var list = is.valueSeq().toArray();

console.log(list);

list.forEach(function(item) {
  
  // Convert Map to Array
  console.log(item.toArray());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.7.5/immutable.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `map.valueSeq().toArray()` vs `[...map.values()]` which one is faster?

Answer (score 26):

Just use `someMap.toIndexedSeq().toArray()` for getting an array of only values.

Answer (score 10):

[`Map.values()`](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/values) returns an ES6 Iterable (as do [`Map.keys()`](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/keys) and [`Map.entries()`](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/entries)), and therefore you can convert to an array with [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) or the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29514855/222356)).

e.g.:

`Array.from(map.values())`

or just

`[...map.values()]`

Comment: Are you talking about immutable.js Map, or ES6 Map?

Comment: Immutable.js. See the links in my answer. This does work with Immutable.js. @mjuopperi if you're finding otherwise, please clarify.