# React 16 iterating over map rendering key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutable.js

I am trying to iterate over an Immutable.js map, to render a component, however although this is rendering, it is also rendering the key to the page. I am not sure why.

```
render() {
    const myMap = new Map({foo: '', bar: 'http://google.com/'})
    const {showFoo, titleAndUrl} = this.props
    return (
      <ul style={[
        styles.container,
        showFoo && styles.container.inline,
      ]}>
        {myMap.map((title, url) => this.renderTab(url, title))}
      </ul>
    )
  }

  renderTab(title, url) {
    const {showFoo, isFoo} = this.props
    return (
      <li key="sb" style={[
        styles.listItem,
        showFoo && styles.listItem.inline,
      ]}>
        <a
          href={url}
          key={title}
          style={[
            styles.link,
            styles.activeLink,
            showFoo && styles.link.inline,
          ]}
          className={isFoo ? "style" : ''}>
          {title}
        </a>
      </li>
    )
  }
}
```

The two names and urls are rendered correctly, however duplicate keys are rendered i.e. foo is rendered twice and so is bar, but one of the foo and bar keys has no styles, which suggests it's being rendered outside of `this.renderTab`

See image:
[image]

Rendered HTML:

```
<ul data-radium="true"
    style="display: flex; align-items: center; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; list-style: none; width: 100%; border-top: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221); height: 48px;">
    foo
    <li data-radium="true" style="display: flex; width: 50%; height: 47px; cursor: default;"><a href=""
                                                                                                class=""
                                                                                                data-radium="true"
                                                                                                style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; width: 100%; text-decoration: none; font-weight: 500; font-size: 16px; color: rgb(0, 31, 91); transition: color 0.1s linear;">foo</a>
    </li>
    bar
    <li data-radium="true" style="display: flex; width: 50%; height: 47px; cursor: default;"><a
            href="http://google.com" class="" data-radium="true"
            style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; width: 100%; text-decoration: none; font-weight: 500; font-size: 16px; color: rgb(0, 31, 91); transition: color 0.1s linear;">bar</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `map()` returns a list, it doesn’t only loop over elements. This might be related for some reason.But I am not sure why it would return the key not the whole component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mixed up the order of your arguments, assigning `title` to `url` and vice versa.

Also, the arguments passed to the callback function for Immutable.Map.map are (1) value, (2) key, so the fist argument is your URL and the second is your title.

Change the line with the call to `map` like so:

```
{myMap.map((url, title) => this.renderTab(title, url))}
```

Another problem is that the list item elements you are rendering all have the same key “sb”, only the key of the “a” elements change, but that is not even needed.

Change the JSX returned by `renderTab` to this:

```
  <li key={title} style={[
    styles.listItem,
    showFoo && styles.listItem.inline,
  ]}>
    <a
      href={url}
      style={[
        styles.link,
        styles.activeLink,
        showFoo && styles.link.inline,
      ]}
      className={isFoo ? "style" : ''}>
      {title}
    </a>
  </li>
```

Finally, the main mistake is that you expect `Immutable.Map.map` to return an array, but it doesn't, it returns another immutable map, so you have to convert the value returned by the map function to an array using [valueSeq](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/valueSeq) and [toArray](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Seq/toArray).

So your map statement should actually look like this:

```
{myMap.map((url, title) => this.renderTab(title, url)).valueSeq().toArray()}
```

→ [see related post on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33148796/immutable-js-map-values-to-array)

Comment: for some reason, using the arguments in that order is incorrect, i would expect title to be the key and url to be the value, however it is the other way round when doing this. However, it is still rendering the duplicate keys

Comment: updated my answer after looking at the documentation of immutable

Comment: OK, this looks fine however the duplicate keys are still rendered

Comment: Added an image so you can see what I mean

Comment: Yup, I see. Could you include the actual HTML code that is rendered?

Comment: Still doesn't solve the issue. I've added the HTML to my original post