# Better way to call `Array.prototype.some()` on es6 Map

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, es6-map

I recently converted some code that made use of regular objects as maps to the new es6 `Map` class. I encountered an issue pretty quickly as, while the `Map` class includes a [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach) like `Array`, it does not include a [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method along with many other `Array.prototype` methods.

To give some context, the original code with regular JS objects looked something like this:

```
var map = {
    entry1: 'test',
    entry2: 'test2'
};

Object.keys(map).some(key => {
    var value = map[key];
    // Do something...found a match
    return true;
});
```

The `Map` class does include an [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries) method but sadly this returns an [`Iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) object. This doesn't include any easy way to access the `Array.prototype` methods either.

I'm curious if there's a clean way to do this or if I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29886552/why-are-objects-not-iterable-in-javascript

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27612713/convert-es6-iterable-to-array

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [`Map#values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) to get an iterator of the values, and the [`spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) or [`Array#from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) (a question of style) to convert the iterator to an array:

```js
const map = new Map([['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]]);

const result = [...map.values()].some((value) => value > 2);

console.log(result);
```

As noted in [@Paulpro comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41538424/better-way-to-call-array-prototype-some-on-es6-map/41538456#comment70282213_41538456) you can use the same method to iterate [`Map#entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries), and [`Map#keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/keys). For example, using `Array#reduce` to convert the Map to an object. As `Array#from` invokes `Map#entries` we don't need to call it explicitly:

```js
const map = new Map([['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]]);

const result = Array.from(map.entries()).reduce((obj, [key, value]) => {
  obj[key] = value;
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: +1, Also, if you want to use the key in the test use `map.keys()` or if you want both the key and value use `map.entries()` and use `([key,value])` for the arrow function's signature.

Comment: True,  an es6 way. Except it doesn't seem like it's any better than what the OP is doing

Comment: Don't use spread syntax for type conversion, use the more explicit `Array.from`. Use spread syntax only when you need to construct an array of multiple elements.

Comment: @Bergi - please elaborate.

Comment: [It's considered better style](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40549565/1048572)

Comment: If it's a stylish preference, with iterators I prefer spread. Although `Array#from` is better when you need the entries. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

Call `Array.from` upon the `Map` object and invoke `some` on that:

```
Array.from(map).some(([key, value]) => /* something */ true)
```

Of course that's horribly inefficient. A much better idea is to define a `some` function that *does* work on any iterator, such as the ones that `Map` provides:

```
function some(it, pred) {
    for (const v of it)
        if (pred(v))
            return true;
    return false;
}

some(map.values(), value => /* something */ true)
```