# Convert first N item in iterable to Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice, infinite, iterable

Something similar to question [Convert ES6 Iterable to Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27612713/convert-es6-iterable-to-array). But I only want first N items. Is there any built-in for me to do so? Or how can I achieve this more elegantly?

```
let N = 100;
function *Z() { for (let i = 0; ; i++) yield i; }

// This wont work
// Array.from(Z()).slice(0, N);
// [...Z()].slice(0, N)

// This works, but a built-in may be preferred
let a = [], t = Z(); for (let i = 0; i < N; i++) a.push(t.next().value);
```

Comment: Just make it a function. They are exactly for situations like this where you don't want to repeat (sometimes inelegant) logic.

Answer (score 8):

To get the first `n` values of an `iterator`, you could use one of:

```
Array.from({length: n}, function(){ return this.next().value; }, iterator);
Array.from({length: n}, (i => () => i.next().value)(iterator));
```

To get the `iterator` of an arbitrary `iterable`, use:

```
const iterator = iterable[Symbol.iterator]();
```

In your case, given a generator function `Z`:

```
Array.from({length: 3}, function(){ return this.next().value; }, Z());
```

If you need this functionality more often, you could create a generator function:

```js
function* take(iterable, length) {
  const iterator = iterable[Symbol.iterator]();
  while (length-- > 0) yield iterator.next().value;
}

// Example:
const set = new Set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);
console.log(...take(set, 3));
```

Comment: I like this approach. You could sugar it up with `[...take(set, 3)]`

Comment: @AluanHaddad Added some sweetener

Comment: does not work if take more elements from an iterator with less elements;

Comment: @TomasJ - True, it would better if the `take()` generator used `for...of` + `break` as in [CRise's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47543877/1869660)

Answer (score 3):

There is no built in method to take only a certain number of items from an iterable (ala something like `take()`). Although your snippet can be somewhat improved with a `for of` loop, which is specifically meant to work with iterables, eg:

```
let a = []; let i = 0; for (let x of Z()) { a.push(x); if (++i === N) break; }
```

Which might be better since your original snippet would continue looping even if there are not N items in the iterable.

Comment: `for..of` loop causes a lot of overhead though, according to the `AirBnB` linting guide

Comment: @AyushGupta Any evidence about the overhead? I think this answer is reasonable as far as there is no such built-in works for the given situation.

Comment: It seems the performace was improved with some V8 engine updated, but seems prettty low a few versions ago

Comment: @AyushGupta Your testcase is targeted on Array, not Iterable. That's not same.

Comment: I had [created a jsperf](https://jsperf.com/iterate-n-element/1), it seems that using `for of` is a bit slow in Chrome, but same performance in Firefox (both 52 and 57). Not knowing why.

Answer (score 0):

A bit shorter and less efficient with `.map`, and a bit safer with custom function:

```js
function *Z() { for (let i = 0; i < 5; ) yield i++; }

function buffer(t, n = -1, a = [], c) { 
    while (n-- && (c = t.next(), !c.done)) a.push(c.value); return a; }

const l = console.log, t = Z()

l( [...Array(3)].map(v => t.next().value) )

l( buffer(t) )
```

Answer (score 0):

> how can I achieve this more elegantly?

One possible elegant solution, using [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops) library:

```
import {pipe, take} from 'iter-ops';

const i = pipe(
    Z(), // your generator result
    take(N) // take up to N values
); //=> Iterable<number>

const arr = [...i]; // your resulting array
```

---

P.S. I'm the author of the library.

Comment: I want to know why you design interface like this? Why not something like `Iter(Z()).take(N)` `Iter<T>::take(n: number) -> Iter<T>` while `Iter implements Iterable`?

Comment: @tsh Because chaining like you showed requires use of a synthetic type (wrapper), which creates type compatibility and integration concerns, whereas my approach works with JavaScript native types only - it takes an iterable, and outputs an iterable, and it also performs better this way.