# Storing all values of an iterator

Tags: javascript, iterator

I wonder if there's a more elegant, better one-liner to store all values of an iterator rather than a for loop:

```
// Create a test URLSearchParams object 
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams("key1=value1&key2=value2"); 

// Get all keys
let keys = [];
for(var key of searchParams.keys()) { 
    keys.push(key);
}
```

Comment: Using spread syntax should work `const keys = [...searchParam.keys()];`

Comment: This is likely a better question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `Array.from(iterator)`

Comment: `searchParams.keys()` already returns an array so. just use the returned array as `let keys = searchParams.keys()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transforming a Javascript iterator into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28718641/transforming-a-javascript-iterator-into-an-array)

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate...voted for a dupe but there were two votes for "opinion based"...when we already have had this question.

Comment: @fubar "The keys() method of the URLSearchParams interface returns an iterator" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/keys.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I did get the [dupe auto-comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60072674/storing-all-values-of-an-iterator?noredirect=1#comment106244544_60072674). However, since the ratio is 2:1 in votes, the close reason is now "opinion-based".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use two different methods:

**[Spead Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):**

```js
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams("key1=value1&key2=value2"); 
let keys1 = [ ... searchParams.keys() ];
console.log(keys1);
```

**[Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)**
**[Spead Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):**

```js
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams("key1=value1&key2=value2"); 
let keys2 = Array.from(searchParams.keys());
console.log(keys2);
```

[Additional Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29514855/1688441)